# Add Two Subscripts to Expression with For Loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, expression

I currently have the vector:

```
myvector <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21)
```

and was hoping to add it to an expression using a `for loop` in `R`.
So far, I've done:

```
new.list <- list()
for(i in myvector){
  new.list[[i]] <- expression(beta[1][i])
}
```

but get the result:

```
[[1]]
expression(beta[1][i])

[[2]]
expression(beta[1][i])

[[3]]
expression(beta[1][i])

[[4]]
expression(beta[1][i])

[[5]]
expression(beta[1][i])

[[6]]
expression(beta[1][i])

[[7]]
expression(beta[1][i])

[[8]]
expression(beta[1][i])

[[9]]
expression(beta[1][i])

[[10]]
expression(beta[1][i])

[[11]]
NULL
```

This continues until the final value in the loop. It's unclear to me why `i` isn't being updated in this loop and how exactly I can ensure it gets updated. I've tried changing the `expression` to `expression(beta[1,i])` and get the same result. When printing `i` normally, it works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: Does `bquote(beta[1][.(i)])` do what you want?

Comment: @Edo I'd expect the first result to be `expression(beta[1][1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, your goal is to have the same list but with the i that changes from 1 to 21.

Try with this:

```
myvector <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21)

new.list <- list()
for(i in myvector){
 new.list[[i]] <- substitute(expression(beta[1][i]), list(i = i))
}
head(new.list)
#> [[1]]
#> expression(beta[1][1])
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> expression(beta[1][2])
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> expression(beta[1][3])
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> expression(beta[1][4])
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> expression(beta[1][5])
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> expression(beta[1][6])
```

`i` couldn't update before because it was included in to an expression.

With `substitute` you can write the same expression but you can specify an environment (a simple list in this case) where the function can find the actual replacement to set in the expression.

---

You can also use a `lapply` instead of a `for` loop:

```
new.list <- lapply(1:21, function(x) substitute(expression(beta[1][i]), list(i = x)))
new.list[setdiff(1:21, myvector)] <- list(NULL)
```

Comment: This is similar to what I want, but I want the result to correspond to `myvector`. So it would skip `11` since its not in the vector.

Comment: oh okay.. did not notice. The code is the same anyway.

Comment: Would it be possible to add a comma between the numbers and use that in the same subscript?

Comment: you mean like this `expression(beta[1,i])` ?

Comment: I was able to do it by adding `expression(beta[paste(1,",",i)])`, oddly when I try to loop through this list and create `ggplot` y-axis titles, the word expression stays while the symbol updates.